# Abstract algebra, Field extension

Tags: finite-fields

Suppose F and H are fields of size $\;q=p^{r}\;$containing$\;GF(p)\;$as subfield.$\;\alpha\;$is a primitive element of F and $\;\beta\;$ is a primitive element of H.$\;m(x)\;$is the minimal polynomial of $\;\alpha\;.\;$Non-zero Elements of both fields satisfy the equation$\;x^{q-1}=1\; .\;\;\;m(x)\;$is divisor of $\;x^{q-1}-1.\;$Hence there is an element in H (say)$\;\beta^{t}\;\;$which is a root $\;\;m(x)\;.\;$
 I want to show that  there exists a field isomorphism $\;\phi:F\to H \;$ which carries zero to zero and $\;\alpha\;$to $\;\beta^{t}\;$
Can you help to prove it? I have tried $\;\phi(\alpha^{j} )=\beta^{tj}\;$ but I could not show that $\;\phi\;$ preserves addition.( This argument is presented by Vera Pless in the  book Introduction to Theory of Error correcting codes.)

Answer (score 0):

You exploit the two isomorphisms
$$
\begin{align}
f :\ &K[x]/(m) \to F\\
     &u + (m) \mapsto u(\alpha)
\end{align}
$$
[which holds because $m$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over the field $K$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_extension#Structure_of_simple_extensions) with $p$ elements,
and
$$
\begin{align}
g :\ &K[x]/(m) \to H\\
     &v + (m) \mapsto v(\beta^{t})
\end{align}
$$
[which holds because $m$ is the minimal polynomial of $\beta^{t}$ over $K$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_extension#Structure_of_simple_extensions).

Note that
$$
\begin{cases}
f(x + (m)) = \alpha, & \text{or $f^{-1}(\alpha) = x + (m)$,}\\
g(x + (m)) = \beta^{t}.\\
\end{cases}
$$

If you compose $g \circ f^{-1}$, you get an isomorphism $F \to H$ such that $g \circ f^{-1} (\alpha) = g(x + (m)) = \beta^{t}$.

Explicitly, if $n$ is the degree of $m$,
$$
g \circ f^{-1} : a_{0} + a_{1} \alpha + \dots + a_{n-1} \alpha^{n-1} \mapsto a_{0} + a_{1} \beta^{t} + \dots + a_{n-1} (\beta^{t})^{n-1},
$$
for $a_{i} \in K$.